# How to make the search in home page in magento

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

Can any one help me to make the search according to the category, price, color in the drop down option in magento at the right side of the home page.

Comment: Help you *make* the search? To get the best help you might want to ask *specific* questions.

Comment: Rajesh, I don't think anyone understands exactly what you are asking for. Can you please edit your question to clarify what it is you need?

Answer (score 0):

Put in an Apache redirect match for your homepage that goes straight to the search page. But search page doesn't sound what you are really after here, you want filtered navigation on a regular category?

You should use a httpd.conf instead of .htaccess, however, in .htaccess, after 'RewriteEngine on' you can add:

```
RedirectMatch ^/$ /nokia-2610-phone.html
```

That is to the nokia phone product page in a demo store.